# Expected an indented block, python

Tags: python

Hello can someone fix it I tried to find solution online but nothing work.

Python Version: 3.7.9

```py
if engine == "example1":
        search = example1(engine)
        request = partial(search.search_for, string)
        all = p.map(request, pages)
            
elif engine == "example2":
        filepath = "list.txt"
        with open(filepath) as fp:
            line = fp.readline()
            count = 1
            while line:
                search = example2(engine)
                request = partial(search.search_for, line.strip())
                all = p.map(request, pages)
                line = fp.readline()
                count += 1
            input(" press close to exit ")
```

Comment: Your indentation seems pretty messed up - for example, the line after `with open` should be indented.

Comment: In addition, the `elif engine == "example2":` is indented one space more than the `if engine == "example1":`

Comment: Also the error tells you where you messed up your indents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the biggest issue is with lines immediately following your `with` statement.  Those should be indented to be part of the context manager scope.

```
elif engine == "example2":
    filepath = "list.txt"
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        line = fp.readline() # <--- note indent
        count = 1            # <--- note indent
        while line:
            search = example2(engine)
            request = partial(search.search_for, line.strip())
            all = p.map(request, pages)
            line = fp.readline()
            count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have 2 intent mistakes.copy this code and try it

```
if engine == "example1":
     search = example1(engine)
     request = partial(search.search_for, string)
     all = p.map(request, pages)
```

## 1. In elif there is one space before the line

```
elif engine == "example2":
    filepath = "list.txt"
```

## 2.After the next line With open you need to leave 4 spaces

```
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        line = fp.readline()
    count = 1
    while line:
        search = example2(engine)
        request = partial(search.search_for, line.strip())
        all = p.map(request, pages)
        line = fp.readline()
        count += 1
    input(" press close to exit ")
```